# Questions related to Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Dear Linear Algebra Experts,

(I am preparing for my exams and not able to solve these questions. I apologize in advance if they are straightforward but please help me to grow and learn this field. I would really appreciate your help.)

If $A \in  M_n$ and $B \in  M_n$  are Hermitian matrices, i.e., $A = A^{\rm H} $ and $B = B^{\rm H}$, where $B$ is positive definite.

(1) Prove that there is a non-singular matrix $Y$ such that $Y^{\rm H}AY = C$ and $Y^{\rm H}BY = D$, where both $C$ and $D$ are diagonal matrices.

(2a) Given a matrix $Y$ such that $Y^{\rm H}AY = C$ and and $Y^{\rm H}BY = D$ where both $C$ and $D$ are diagonal (not necessarily related to the above question 1), prove that the columns of $Y$ are eigenvectors of the following generalized eigenvalue problem $$Ay=\lambda B y$$

(2b) Describe how the corresponding eigenvalues can be obtained from $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing some information? For example, in (1), that $AB= BA$?

Comment: I also got some hint, but not sure how it fits:

Apply Cholseky Factorization $B=LL^{\rm H}$ and apply the spectral factorization on the matrix $L^{-1} A L^{-H}$ and use the result to form Y. One of the matrices $C$ and $D$ will end up being the identity matrix.

Comment: It *is* true because of the additional hypothesis that $B$ is positive definite. So you diagonalize $A$ with respect to the $B$-inner product.

Comment: @Ian: I have no idea what your comment means. I'm talking about applying the spectral theorem to diagonalize the linear map $A$ with respect to the hermitian inner product given by $\langle z,w\rangle = z^*Bw$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You transform $B$ to the identity with a matrix $Z$.
$$Z^{\star}BZ=I$$
$A$ gets transformed to $Z^{\star}AZ$, still hermitian. Now, we don't want to alter the result from $B$ ( the indentity), but want to transform $Z^{\star}AZ$ to a diagonal. So we find $T$ unitary so that $T^{\star}(Z^{\star}AZ) T= C$. Note that  $Z$ does not change the $I$. Summing up
$$Z^{\star}T^{\star}ATZ = C \\
Z^{\star}T^{\star}BTZ = I$$ 
So we take $Y=TZ$.

The other question: if 
$$Y^{\star}AY=C\\
Y^{\star}BY= D$$
then 
$$AY =Y^{\star}\ ^{-1}C=Y^{\star}\ ^{-1}D \cdot D^{-1}C =BY \cdot D^{-1}C$$
We see that the column $i$ of $Y$ satisfies 
$$(Ac_i - \lambda_iB) c_i=0$$ where $D^{-1}C = \text{diag}(\lambda_i)$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate your attempt so much. Based on your proofs, above is my take (just re-writting in a different way). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the proof given by "orangeskid", below is my take (re-writting in a slightly different way). Please experts correct me if I am wrong.

(1) 
Since $B$ is a positive definite and Hermitian matrix, then after similarity transformation of $B$ into a diagonal matrix $D$. The matrix $D$ can be factorized $$D = T^{{\rm H}/2} T^{1/2},$$ where $T$ is another diagonal matrix.

Now we plug-in the factorized form of $D$ such that 
$$ Y^{\rm H} B Y = D = T^{{\rm H}/2} T^{1/2} \\ \Leftrightarrow T^{-{\rm H}/2} Y^{\rm H} B Y T^{-1/2} = I \\ \Leftrightarrow \left(Y T^{-1/2}\right)^{\rm H} B \left(Y T^{-1/2}\right) = I.$$

Now define $Z = Y T^{-1/2} \Leftrightarrow Y = Z T^{1/2} $ such that 
$$Y^{\rm H} A Y = C \Leftrightarrow \left(Z T^{-1/2}\right)^{\rm H} B \left(Z T^{-1/2}\right) = C$$.

(2) if 
$$Y^{\rm H}AY=C \\
Y^{\rm H}BY= D \Leftrightarrow BY = Y^{-{\rm H}} D.$$
then (assuming $D$ is invertible as $B$ is Hermitian)
$$AY =Y^{-{\rm H}}C= \underbrace{Y^{-{\rm H}} D}_{B Y} D^{-1} C = BY \cdot D^{-1}C$$

We see that the column $i$ of $Y$ satisfies 
$$(Au_i - \lambda_iB u_i) =0$$ where $D^{-1}C = \text{diag}(\lambda_i)$.